# yesod PUT and DELETE using hidden _method parameter

Tags: httprequest, yesod

Is there an easy way to have yesod read a POST request as a PUT or DELETE when it has a special parameter: `_method=DELETE`? And render forms with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesod uses the [methodOverride middleware](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra-2.1.1.1/docs/Network-Wai-Middleware-MethodOverride.html) by default which allows this. When I use this approach, I just put it into the `action` attribute of the form, e.g.:

```
<form method=post action=@{SomeRouteR}?_method=DELETE>
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this and it still goes through as a POST.

Comment: It works with a standard setup, e.g. https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/random-code-snippets/method-override. You might have different middlewares configured, but I can't tell from the information you've provided.

Comment: I just ran into the fact myself that the scaffolded site does *not* have methodOverride enabled by default. If that's the issue you're running into, you need to edit your Application.hs, find the code that says `logWare app`, and replace it with `logWare $ methodOverride app`. You'll need to include an import for `Network.Wai.Middleware.MethodOverride` as well.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Thanks! :)